# Flash size of a bare metal ARM program

Tags: gcc, arm

How to know the flash size of a bare metal arm code. If I have the elf is it possible to know how much flash will be required to store the program? For example if I have the elf file that is supposed to go into a ARM based MCU, how can I determine how much of the MCU's flash will be consumed by the code?

Comment: @dwelch He says he has the elf file already.

Comment: then simply use gnu tools...readelf, objdump, etc.

Comment: [`size`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?size) is standard for this.  The only caveat is if you have huge holes in the ELF format, they may make a binary flash image seem huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ELF headers should contain the information you need. You can use either the `objdump` (with -h) or `readelf` tool to read these. Those tools should be included with your toolchain.

Basically, you're looking to add up the size all the loadable sections, such as `.text` and `.data`. Look for the `LOAD` flag in the output from `objdump`, for example.

You can ignore non-loadable sections such as `.comment`, `.debug` and `.bss`· Some of those are there for the benefit of the debugger, for example, and some are just placeholders for memory that will be used by the program at run time, but contains no pre-existing data.

When I say "add up the size", that's not strictly true; the linker will have already allocated each section to a specific address in flash (I'm assuming your program will run directly from ROM), so you need to find the end-address of the last section to determine how much is left.

Comment: Or just you *toolprefix*-size which is made for this purpose, if it is available.

Comment: @artlessnoise thanks man! Thats precisely what I was looking for! :)

Comment: I find the output of `size` to be unsatisfactory; too many hidden assumptions. As I said above, what you're really looking for is the last-used address in flash.